# Set "readrate" to a high value for fixed time duration in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hls, mpeg

I'm trying to restream HLS livestream input to MPEG-TS livestream output using FFmpeg. It works with the following command, but with a small issue

Command:

```
ffmpeg -readrate 1 -fflags nobuffer -live_start_index -1 -http_persistent 0 -i <input> -map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1800k -bufsize 3000k -vf "scale=1920:1080,format=yuv420p" -map 0:a:0 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -f mpegts <output>
```

The issue: output is delayed by around 10 seconds compared to the input. There seems to be a way to work-around this issue by setting the `-readrate` value to slightly greater than 1. However this makes the output have glitches after a few seconds. And then the glitches continue to be there forever. The amount of time it takes to get into the "glitchy" period is inversely proportional to the `-readrate` value. This is perfectly logical and as expected.

Now I'm trying to find a way to get rid of these glitches, hence the question:

Is there any way to specify the `-readrate` value only for the starting few seconds of the livestream? This way, once the output catches up with the input, `-readrate` should go back to 1.

Thank you

Edit: adding `-tune zerolatency` does help a bit, but there is still the unwanted delay. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: This is due to a large default keyframe interval and the client reading the output after ffmpeg has already started. Start the client first and set a low KF interval using `-g X` where X is 1 to 4 times the framerate.

Comment: Thanks. Is it same as `-force_key_frames` option?

Comment: No, but it can be used to similar effect. fkf allows more flexible specification.

Comment: It seems to work, but in rather hit-or-miss manner. The only thing which seems to work reliably is setting `-readrate` value a bit above 1. Then output catches up with the input at least after some time. However the output starts glitching thereafter. Is there any way to reset `-readrate` value to 1 once the output has caught up with the input?

Comment: @Gyan would you be able to point me to the approximate location in code? I can try to patch the code and test whether my theory works